# Abrir div via ajax

Tags: php, javascript

Gelera, preciso abrir uma `div` via ajax passando uma `ID` via `POST`. Onde estou errando.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="retorno_galeria">
    <a onclick="galeria_id(this.id,' . $gal["id"] . ');" href="#">
   </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function galeria_id(id) {
    var idGaleria = (this.value.id);
    $.post(URL + 'Ajax/galeria', {val: idGaleria}, function (busca) {
        $('#retorno_galeria').html(busca);
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
case 'galeria':

    $char = $_POST['val'];

    $tbody .= 'Teste retorno galeria ' . $char . '';

    $retorno = $tbody;

break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="retorno_galeria">
    <a onclick="galeria_id(this.id)" id="<?=$gal["id"]; ?>" href="#">
      LINK
    </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
function galeria_id(id) {
    $.post(URL + 'Ajax/galeria', {val: id}, function (busca) {
        $('#retorno_galeria').html(busca);
    });
}
```

**PHP** Tá certo.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Obrigado